# Mac OS Big Sur : how to make my display arrangement stayed permanently?

Tags: mac, display, external-display, display-settings, macos-bigsur

## Situation :

I have a MacBook Pro 16"

[image]

I configured it to run with 3 more monitors like do :

[image]

## Problem :

When I reboot my Mac sometimes from sleep, it messed up all my displays arrangement completely & horribly.

After rebooted, this still happening, can someone please tell me a permanent solution how to make my display arrangement stayed permanently.

Comment: It's a common issue - basically, you have to make the screens wake earlier [also never power them off while the Mac thinks they're connected, they should only ever be in standby unless the Mac is also powered down]. Sometimes it's a case of poking any button on the display just to jog its elbow a bit, then wake the Mac.

Comment: btw, `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist` is a kind of 'base setup' used for boot. Your own personal prefs are in `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.windowserver.[UUID].plist`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just rebooted 3 times, log out & log back in 2 times,  and these steps below seems to persist my displays arrangement now.

> /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist

[image]

I removed **write** access permission from the **system**

[image]

Comment: Neither reboot nor logout will take long enough for the displays to lose connection, so I doubt it's a valid test.

Comment: You are right. I noticed it messed again. :(